# How do I view all Build macro values for a VS C# .NET 6 project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, it is easy to get the complete list of all available build macro values for any C++ project.  I am talking about values like `$(OutDir)`, `$(Configuration)`, `$(Platform)` etc.

How do I do this for C# projects?

To illustrate, for C++,

1. Go to project properties
2. Go to any editable value, for example ***C/C++ >> General >> Additional Include Directories***
3. Click the dropdown and choose "Edit"
4. Then in the resulting dialog choose "Macros"

[image]

There they all are.  The resulting list of every single available macro shows it *as it evaluates for that project only*.

[image]

This is exactly what I want.  Is there some equivalent of this in the project properties of a C# project?  Because I've searched high and low and can find none.

Comment: Sorry, through internal discussions, there is nothing like that for c#. If anyone knows something related, comments are welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  A shame if it's not available.  What prompted my question is that I've got one single C# project for which the `$(OutDir)` macro is not evaluating correctly like all the others and I cannot figure out why.  A feature like this would be extremely helpful in such situations.  I think maybe I'll make some sort of project suggestion through the VS feedback feature

Comment: I also share this same concern. So I created an [issue at MS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Provide-a-list-of-all-of-a-projects-cur/10464327). If you believe this feature is still missing, please up-vote.

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio 2019 has this for C# projects, and I have no idea why this very useful feature is not transferred to Visual Studio 2022! It may not be a good solution, but could you install VS 2019 Community? Here is what you can see in VS 2019:

[image]

Alternatively, referring to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2022#macros), add the following commands to the pre/post build events once and save the text from the Output panel, as a reference:

```
echo ConfigurationName: $(ConfigurationName)
echo OutDir: $(OutDir)
echo DevEnvDir: $(DevEnvDir)
echo PlatformName: $(PlatformName)
echo ProjectDir: $(ProjectDir)
echo ProjectPath: $(ProjectPath)
echo ProjectName: $(ProjectName)
echo ProjectFileName: $(ProjectFileName)
echo ProjectExt: $(ProjectExt)
echo SolutionDir: $(SolutionDir)
echo SolutionPath: $(SolutionPath)
echo SolutionName: $(SolutionName)
echo SolutionFileName: $(SolutionFileName)
echo SolutionExt: $(SolutionExt)
echo TargetDir: $(TargetDir)
echo TargetPath: $(TargetPath)
echo TargetName: $(TargetName)
echo TargetFileName: $(TargetFileName)
echo TargetExt: $(TargetExt)
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah when they redesigned the UI for project settings they appear to have gotten rid of that incredibly useful list.    Unfortunately I would have to say that installing VS2019 just for this one thing is probably not something I'm willing to do.    But I do like the trick of just dumping the variables.  I should have thought about that.  Thank you!

Comment: Apparently this is now in 2022

Comment: @AMG I still cannot see it on version 17.7.2. Can you explain how you're accessing it or share a screenshot?