What path $(OpenALPRDistDir) points to
I put openalpr-2.3.0 folder on my desktop folder, there is a C++ project to compile native assemblies.
But I get many linker errors, there is a $(OpenALPRDistDir), That I don't know where it points, and libtesseract.. and liblept.. and support.lib and other libraries should be there.
does anyone know where is this folder? or how to create it?

In Visual Studio $(someName) is the syntax for an IDE variable (which VS calls a macro) named someName so $(OpenALPRDistDir) would represent an IDE variable named OpenALPRDistDir. To see the value of this type of variable see the question part of this question which explains the c++ behavior of the IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463462/how-do-i-view-all-build-macro-values-for-a-vs-c-sharp-net-6-project
